# knn 'bayes' versus 'majority voting'

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm knn uses 'majority voting' to classify an object while knn described on page 39 of http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf states 'KNN applies Bayes rule and classifies the test observation x0 to
the class with the largest probability.'

Which implementation should I choose and under what conditions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statement are the same. Because Bayes error rate is coming from  minimizing the 0-1 loss (classifications loss). And majority vote will achieve such goal.

Where, the Bayes error is

$$
1 - E~(\max_j P(Y=j|X))
$$

The 0-1 loss will be minimized, if we assign the probability

$$
P(Y=j|X)=\frac 1 K \sum_{i \in \text{neighbor}} I(y_i=j) 
$$

where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

---

Numerical example: suppose we are doing binary classification $Y$ can be $0$ or $1$. In addition, we use $N=5$, in $5$ neighbors there are $2$ vote for class $0$ and $3$ vote for class $1$.

If we assign $Y=1$, the 0-1 loss will be minimized, and the Bayes error rate is $\frac 2 5$.

Comment: ' If we assign $Y=1$, the 0-1 loss will be minimized, and the Bayes error rate is $\frac 2 5$.  '  should be  ' If we assign $Y=1$, the 0-1 loss will be minimized, and the Bayes error rate is $\frac 3 5$.  ' as ' 3 vote for class 1 ' ?

Comment: ' If we assign $Y=1$, the 0-1 loss will be minimized, and the Bayes error rate is $\frac 2 5$.  '  if 2 (not 3) vote for class 1 ?